# xCode 6.1.1 Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT,subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have problems when running my application with xCode 6.1.1. In words, the application logs in into facebook and has to display another view. In console the only thing I see is "(lldb)", following here's the stack trace.

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xae9d1, 0x000000010a4158ad libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 77, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x000000010a4158ad libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 77
    frame #1: 0x000000010802867a ciao`ciao.ViewController.prepareForSegue (segue=0x00007f9271c653a0, sender=Some, self=0x00007f9271d87110)(ObjectiveC.UIStoryboardSegue, sender : Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>) -> () + 890 at ViewController.swift:47
    frame #2: 0x000000010802894b ciao`@objc ciao.ViewController.prepareForSegue (ciao.ViewController)(ObjectiveC.UIStoryboardSegue, sender : Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>) -> () + 75 at ViewController.swift:0
    frame #3: 0x000000010931e71c UIKit`-[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 151
    frame #4: 0x000000010802a5de ciao`ciao.ViewController.(connection=Some, user=Some, error=None, self=0x00007f9271d87110) -> (Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.FBLoginView>, user : ObjectiveC.FBGraphUser) -> ()).(closure #1) + 1534 at ViewController.swift:39
    frame #5: 0x000000010802aa4a ciao`reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.FBRequestConnection>, @owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>, @owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.NSError>) -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_unowned @objc_block (@unowned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.FBRequestConnection>, @unowned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>, @unowned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.NSError>) -> (@unowned ()) + 90 at ViewController.swift:37
    frame #6: 0x0000000108032944 ciao`__51-[FBRequestConnection completeWithResults:orError:]_block_invoke657(.block_descriptor=0x00007f9271c63250, task=<unavailable>) + 65 at FBRequestConnection.m:1400
    frame #7: 0x000000010804b749 ciao`__39-[FBTask dependentTaskWithBlock:queue:]_block_invoke_2(.block_descriptor=0x00007f9271c63390) + 30 at FBTask.m:257
    frame #8: 0x000000010a80bba6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    frame #9: 0x000000010a8297f4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #10: 0x000000010a8128fb libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 949
    frame #11: 0x0000000108265fe9 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    frame #12: 0x0000000108228eeb CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2043
    frame #13: 0x0000000108228486 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    frame #14: 0x000000010d3269f0 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #15: 0x0000000108dcc420 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
    frame #16: 0x000000010802bcae ciao`top_level_code + 78 at AppDelegate.swift:12
    frame #17: 0x000000010802bcea ciao`main + 42 at AppDelegate.swift:0
    frame #18: 0x000000010a85e145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Anyone has suggestions?

Here's the prepareForSegue function :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (segue.identifier=="showView"){
            var vc:NewViewController = segue.destinationViewController as NewViewController
            vc.firstName=self.firstName
            vc.lastName=self.lastName
            vc.email=self.email
        }

    }
```

Comment: There is a reference to a `prepareForSegue` call. Could you show us this part of your code ?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the `vc:NewViewController = ...` line, what kind of object is `segue.destinationViewController` reported as by the debugger?

Comment: Is the Valid Architecture or Support Platforms wrong? Check Build Settings -> Valid Architecture or Support Platforms. Does FB support architecture i386?

Comment: @PhillipMills I tried what you suggest and get that segue.destinationViewController is of type UITabBarController

Comment: Sounds like there's something wrong with your segue since it's giving you a type of controller that doesn't match what you expect.  It all seems a bit odd since a `UITabBarController ` should only be used as a top-level controller and certainly not a segue destination.

Comment: @PhillipMills so what do you suggest?

Comment: Don't try to segue to a `UITabBarController`.  Make it the root controller of your app.  See Apple's section on tab bar controllers in the "View Controller Catalog for iOS" documentation.

Comment: thanks for the help! appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Is `NewViewController` embedded in a navigation controller?

Then maybe you could try this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier=="showView"){
       let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController 
let vc = navigationController.topViewController as NewViewController
        vc.firstName=self.firstName
        vc.lastName=self.lastName
        vc.email=self.email
    }
}
```

Other potential culprits include the segue identifier, although this would probably produce a more helpful error message.

Do what @PhilipMills suggested and check what is the actual destination controller at runtime.

Comment: having an UITabBarController I don't have a topViewController

Comment: Why do you need a segue then?

Comment: In my first view controller I have the FB Login Button, and after a successful login I want to redirect the user to a view where he can navigate using the tab bar.. I need to perform the segue between the first view controller and the UITabBarController